# Error in makebin(data, file) : 'sid' invalid

Tags: r

I am getting the same error "Error in makebin(data, file) : 'sid' invalid"
running cspade on the small dataset below.  Both my transactionID and eventID are ordered blockwise (as somebody mentioned in another post that they hsould be).  So I don't see any reason for that error.  Please let me know what could be the problem.

```
items             transactionID sequenceID    eventID
1  {item=/}                     1           1 1458565800
2  {item=/login}                2           2 1458565803
3  {item=/profile}              3           3 1458565811
4  {item=/shop_list}            4           4 1458565814
5  {item=/}                     5           1 1458565912
6  {item=/login}                6           2 1458565915
7  {item=/shop_list}            7           3 1458565918
8  {item=/}                     8           1 1458565802
9  {item=/login}                9           2 1458565808
10 {item=/profile}              10          3 1458565812
11 {item=/product}              11          4 1458565818
12 {item=/}                     12          1 1458565911
13 {item=/login}                13          2 1458565916
14 {item=/shop_list}            14          3 1458565922
15 {item=/profile}              15          4 1458565927
16 {item=/contact}              16          5 1458565929
17 {item=/profile}              17          6 1458565933

traffic  <- read.csv("C:\\buczaal1\\RProg\\web_traffic.csv")
traffic_data <- data.frame(item=traffic$Page)
traffic.tran <- as(traffic_data, "transactions")
transactionInfo(traffic.tran)$sequenceID <- traffic$Seq
transactionInfo(traffic.tran)$eventID <- traffic$Timestamp
frequent_pattern <- cspade(traffic.tran, parameter= list(support=0.3))
```